# Customising Django admin TabularInline default field

Tags: django, django-admin, photologue

I have a TabularInline admin layout, all works fine except I'd like to have it show something other than the `Obj.__unicode__` value on the top left of each row.

My TabularInline is a photologue ImageModel model, so I'd like it to show me the thumbnail instead of the regular `__unicode__` result.

I tried to change `__unicode__` to output the thumbnail, which works, except the HTML is escaped so I get `<img src="XXX"...... etc`

Is there an easy way to mark my `__unicode__` method as a safe string? Or a way to override the property the admin chooses to display?

I've tried this:

```
__unicode__.is_safe = True
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can customize the template for you TabularInline to make it look the way you want. I think it's a better idea then hacking `__unicode__`:

```
class PhotoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Photo
    template = 'photologue/photoinline.html'
```

The easiest way to create your is to copy and customize the default `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html` template.

Comment: yes - that's the way I'd go - I've since created a new Widget to show the image (copied from djangosnippets)